# Display Warning Message if Any Form Fields are Blank - Python/CGI/HTML

Tags: python, cgi

I have a small application that displays a form with four fields. I'm trying to build in some validation so that a warning message is displayed if one or all of the fields are blank when a user clicks submit. Right now, the message is displayed if one or more of the fields are blank but if all of the fields are blank, it does not show anything.

```
# if the form was submitted, insert data into the database and show status message
if form:
    company_name = form.getvalue("company_name")
    customer_contact_name = form.getvalue("contact_name")
    customer_contact_phone = form.getvalue("customer_contact_phone")
    customer_contact_email = form.getvalue("customer_contact_email")

    # check if all fields are filled in
    if not all(
        [
            company_name,
            customer_contact_name,
            customer_contact_phone,
            customer_contact_email,
        ]
    ):
        # show warning message if any field is blank
        html += """<p class="warning_message">Please enter in all fields.</p>"""

    else:
        # check if the customer already exists
        query = "SELECT * FROM Sales_Portal WHERE company_name=%s"
        values = company_name
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        existing_customer = cursor.fetchone()

        if existing_customer:
            # show warning message if customer already exists in database
            html += """<p class="warning_message">The customer {} already exists! Please enter a new customer.</p>""".format(
                company_name
            )
        else:
            # insert the customer into the database
            query = """
                INSERT INTO Sales_Portal (company_name, customer_contact_name, customer_contact_phone, customer_contact_email)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
            """
            values = (
                company_name,
                customer_contact_name,
                customer_contact_phone,
                customer_contact_email,
            )
            cursor.execute(query, values)
            conn.commit()
            # show success message if customer added successfully
            html += """<p class="success_message">{} has been added successfully.</p>""".format(
                company_name
            )

# add the form and the button to show all customers
html += """
    <form method="GET" action="" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="company_name">Company Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name"><br>
        <label for="contact_name">Primary Contact:</label>
        <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name"><br>
        <label for="customer_contact_phone">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" name="customer_contact_phone" id="customer_contact_phone"><br>
        <label for="customer_contact_email">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="customer_contact_email" id="customer_contact_email"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset">
    </form>
"""
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I expected my code to display a message if one or all the fields are blank but it does not show anything if all fields are blank.